# How to setup Cloudflare when I don't have authority over the parent domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, cloudflare

I'm new to cloudflare and have a handful of web servers I'd like to run through it:
(I'd ask this on cloudflare's forum but I corrected a typo in my email address for the free cloudflare service and they keep sending the forum confirmation link to the typo address)

```
  www.my.domain.net
  hosta.my.domain.net
  hostb.my.domain.net
```

I've tried working through the cloudflare setup page and when it did the domain search for the hosts I entered, it instructed me
to change the nameservers for domain.net to "bill.ns.cloudflare.com" and 
"tony.ns.cloudflare.com". The thing is, I don't have authority over the parent domain, domain.net.

What's the best way to handle this? My (Bind) SOA record looks (similar) to this:

```
  IN NS ns1.my.domain.net.
  IN NS ns2.my.domain.net.
  IN A 1xx.9x.4x.1
  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx ptr ip4:1xx.x2.x3.x3 ip4:1xx.x2.x3.x4 include:other.domain.net include:spf.protection.outlook.com ?all"
```

I'm not sure changing the NS lines to "bill" and "tony" on cloudflare would be the
right thing to do for my.domain.net since cloudflare seems to be wanting me to 
change the DNS for the entire parent domain.

Is there a way to only send `www`, `hosta` and `hostb` through cloudflare and leave the
rest of my.domain.net "un-proxied" through cloudflare? Ideally, since I have no cloudflare-fu, I would setup a test host and experiment first before moving everything over.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "my.domain.net" do you already have a "my" subdomain set up that has the hostnames that you want to have hosted through cloudflare?

When people talk about "domains" what they really mean are subdomains.  `domain.net` is actually a subdomain of `net`. DNS operates at each subdomain level. All of the hostnames in a given subdomain will have to resolve from the same servers, so you can't configure `mail.domain.net` to resolve from one DNS server while a different server resolves `www.domain.net`.

However, if you were to create a subdomain of `domain.net`, for instance `my.domain.net` then the owner of `domain.net` can delegate DNS service for that subdomain without surrendering complete control of `domain.net`.

In `bind`, this would be configured in the `domain.net` zonefile to delegate `my.domain.net` to cloudflare's servers (assuming `domain.net.` is the origin for this zonefile, otherwise you should spell out the subdomain including the terminating dot: `my.domain.net.`):

```
my NS bill.ns.cloudflare.com.
my NS tony.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

Then you would use `www.my.domain.net` `hosta.my.domain.net` etc.  Since you're using cloudflare's DNS servers, you would not require glue records with bill and tony's IP addresses (since those resolve from a completely different domain).

Comment: Yes, `my.domain.net` is setup on the Internet, but not in Cloudflare. It currently has ~20 hosts with routable IPv4 addys (`hosta.my.domain.net`, `hostb.my.domain.net`,etc) as well as some CNAMEs (probably not relevant).  When I add `my.domain.net` to Cloudflare's _Create and manage your websites_ page I get the error below. It seems to want to search for hosts on `domain.net` instead?
**We were unable to identify my.domain.net as a registered domain. Please ensure you are providing the root domain and not any subdomains (e.g., example.com, not subdomain.example.com) (Code: 1099)**